# i dont receive firebase otp on some android devices

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am maintaining an android app which uses `firebase otp` for authentication. The app is live and works on most of the devices, but `otp` is not received on `Android P` devices.

I am guessing this is something to do with compatible versions, any help would be appreciated.

**This is the log error I am getting:**

> I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod()
>   returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@2492342

**APP GRADLE:**

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 21
        versionName "1.9.5"
        multiDexEnabled = true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        //debuggable true
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        //debuggable true
    }
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.42.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
implementation 'com.flyco.banner:FlycoBanner_Lib:1.1.8@aar'
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.4@aar'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.fxn769:pix:1.4.4'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.0'
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'






AND PROJECT GRADLE
buildscript {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Same happens to me, But it turns out that those devices doesn't have google play services. The device which don't have google play services don't receive OTP

Comment: You mean phone-number authentication?

Comment: yes phone authentication, and sir my phone has google play services installed, this issue has been arising past couple of days